# jQuery fluid full-width text with part of a responsive grid

Tags: jquery, css, resize, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I'm trying to use [FitText](http://fittextjs.com/) to resize the main h1 on my page to the full window width on my responsive site, but only when the window is below a certain width.

I have used media queries to define the font size as 148px for all widths greater than 1170px, 118px for width less than 1170, then at 940px I want FitText to take over and resize the h1 so it becomes fluid, stretching the full width of the browser window as it's resized. I'm using the following jQuery for this:

```
var title = $("header h1");
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ( $(window).width() < 940) {
        $(title).fitText(0.47);
    }
});
```

This works if the browser starts wider than 940px and is then resized down. However, the effect doesn't stop, and if the browser window is widened again, the text continues to scale along with it.

Here's a fiddle (might have to stretch across multiple monitors and reload to see the starting size before scaling): http://jsfiddle.net/segFE/1/

Ideally, I would like the effect to stop after the browser window reaches > 940px again and revert back to the standard size defined in my CSS.

I have tried adding another if condition to stop the function, but the way I wrote it doesn't seem to be working:

```
var title = $("header h1");
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ( $(window).width() < 940) {
        $(title).fitText(0.47);
    }
    if ( $(window).width() > 940) {
        stop();
    }
});
```

Any ideas on how I could get this working would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you just set the `maxFontSize` property?

Comment: This doesn't work because I have a break point at 1170 with a smaller font size than the largest width. If I set the maxFontSize property to the larger size, it still exhibits the same issue below that 1170 breakpoint. Thank you for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the FitText doc:

> Use this plugin on your responsive design to achieve scalable headlines that fill the width *of the parent element*.

I think you can avoid using jQuery all together and using media queries, just wrap the h1 in a div or something and set a fixed width on *that* for the 1170+ and >940 sizes.

Comment: This did work, thank you. I was hoping to avoid extra markup but this works so well that it's not too big of an issue. Thanks!